# Visual Studio "New Project" Dialog - Set available tests

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know how to include NUnit (for example) as one of the available test types in the Visual Studio 2010 "New Project" dialog for MVC projects and / or as an installed template in the New Project window?

From memory, it requires a number of steps including playing with the registry, copying files to specific folders, secret incantations and ritual sacrifice.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx%28VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Huh.  Seems kind of obvious now that you point me to it.  Should've been less specific in my Bing search terms, I guess.  Thanks!